# Where is the problem on that bouncing ball code

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-physics, turtle-graphics

When I run that code it's just showing an empty window with my title and background and then it stops responding
sorry for my English

I used original python ,visual studio code , 
online python editor

```py
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("bouncing pysics")
wn.bgcolor("orange")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("green")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0,-1)
ball.dy = -1
ball.dy_2 = 1
first_location = ball.ycor()
while True:
    while first_location < -280:
        while ball.ycor() < 290:
            ball.sety(ball.ycor() - ball.dy_2)
        wn.update()
        last_location = ball.ycor()
        first_location = (last_location + first_location) / 2
        while ball.ycor() > first_location:
            ball.sety(ball.ycor() - ball.dy)
        wn.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't make heads or tails of your bouncing logic but here's why your code does nothing:

```
ball.goto(0,-1)
# ...
first_location = ball.ycor()
while True:
    while first_location < -280:
```

Entering the outer `while` loop, `first_location` is set to -1 (the ball's initial Y position.)  Since the condition of the inner `while` loop isn't met (-1 is *greater* than -280) the inner loop never runs so we repeat doing nothing over and over.